# Django Polls tutorial. I'm getting a database error 1146

Tags: django-admin

So I am running through the Django polls tutorial. Trying to get the admin site to work for me. I can load it up and it looks great then I click on polls and then add a poll. Then I enter the name and the pub_date and time. Then I hit the save button and I get this big long error:

DatabaseError at /admin/pollsTest/poll/add/
(1146, "Table 'mydb.django_admin_log' doesn't exist")

I have been following the tutorial to the T. I have django.contrib.admin in the installed_apps file. I ran a syncdb. I edited the urls.py file to include all the admin code. And still no luck. Am I missing something obvious?

I have opened up my sql database and in fact the table does not exist. So I think somehow the syncdb command is not going through. Also when I run the syncdb command the output from the command line says:

```
...File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySWLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler raiseclass, errorvalue django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1050, "Table 'polls_poll' already exists")
```

Which makes sense. the syncdb is only supposed to add tables that don't currently exist right? Am I supposed to get that kind of an error (like some django module is catching it and taking care of it)? I feel like it may be hitting this error and then crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Happens if you run manage.py syncdb before adding django.contrib.admin to installed_apps. Just run syncdb again to fix.
Cheers!